# How to open WebView in Popup Window in AsyncTask

Tags: android, webview

Editing code as per Armaan suggestion : Calling ImageView inside onPostExecute crashing application

Details : If i put close button and call its onClickListener inside onPostExecute it would crash, not sure what could be reason :

```
public class Async extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

ListView _rssFeedListView;
List<JSONObject> jobs;
List<RssFeedStructure> rssStr;
private BlogAdapter _adapter;
TextView textview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);
    _rssFeedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rssfeed_listview);

    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loading);
    RssFeedTask rssTask = new RssFeedTask();
    rssTask.execute();

}


private class RssFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String response = "";
    PopupWindow popupWindow;
    ImageView image; 


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            String feed = "http://someurl";
            XmlHandler rh = new XmlHandler();
            rssStr = rh.getLatestArticles(feed);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return response;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (rssStr != null) {

            _adapter = new BlogAdapter(Async.this, rssStr);
            _rssFeedListView.setAdapter(_adapter);
            textview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            _rssFeedListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
                            View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_popup_layout, null); 

                            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(layout, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            WebView web = (WebView)layout.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                            image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.closebutton);

                            web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                            web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                            web.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(10);
                            web.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
                            web.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);

                            String text = "<html><body style=\"text-align:justify\"> %s </body></Html>";
                            String summary = rssStr.get(position).getEncodedContent();

                            Log.d("String", summary);
                            web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, String.format(text, summary), "text/html", "UTF-8",null);
                            popupWindow.showAtLocation(view,Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

                            image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v)
                     {
                            popupWindow.dismiss(); 
                     } 
             });

                      }
            });



        }

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Create Popupwindow Like this

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
            View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_popup_layout, null);  
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                    layout, 
                       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                             LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

WebView web = (WebView)layout.findViewbyId(R.id.webView1);
popupWindow.showAtLocation(view,Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

and create new_popup_layout layout file with webview like this:

```
         <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />
    </TableRow>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: Armaan, onClick of back button it is exiting application. Is there any way if i press back button it would remain on same activity ?

Comment: This is my listview and onClick of ListItem I am showing this dialog, now after reading content in dialog, generally user would want to go back and see other list item but in this case if i press back button it would close activity and exit application. I know how to get back button event but m not sure what is the ideal solution to get what i want. Any idea ?

Comment: or can we have close button as it is shown in this image : http://i.stack.imgur.com/97aJX.png

Comment: Oops it is messing up webview layout...I guess something wrong with properties of <ImageView>

Comment: try this edited answer. and if it doesn't work then do inform.

Comment: Nop it didn't work :) This was even more messy. Can you please check from your side first and then suggest. Thanks

Comment: i have made the change. its woking fine for me. try yourself. if it doesn't work then do change in gravity and height width and other things.do some modifications yourself.

Comment: Ya thanks Armaan, I will do those change, but what is the code you call onClick of this ImageView ?

Comment: popupWindow.dismiss(); to dissmiss the popup.

Comment: Thanks Armaan, the UI issue got resolved. Now if i am putting this listener inside "onPostExecute" it won't work because it is calling immediately after creation of popup window. Then where else i can put this ? Updating code in Question. Thanks

Comment: create one function in activity for showing popup. means put all code from post execute to that function and call that function from postexecute. try that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom dialogs, all you need to do is in your custom dialog's layout file put a `WebView` and then in your code give a source `URL` to your `WebView` according to the selected item in your `ListView`. For how to make a custom dialog take a look at here
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Comment: Onur, I tried as u suggested from that example but it didn't work. I have edited my code and placed error in question, please confirm it

Comment: your code for custom layout seems to much completed but apparently you found the solution

Comment: Yes Onur, thanks for your time and looking into it. Appreciate your efforts